# how to get value from list / tk grid

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter, grid

I am using the `tkinter` grid for user input that have 5 cols and 10 rows.

How to save this all data in `pandas dataframe` and export to `excel`?

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
entries = []

for i in range(10):
    en = Entry(root)
    en.grid(row=i+1, column=0)
    en1 = Entry(root)
    en1.grid(row=i+1, column=1)
    entries.append([en,en1])

def hallo():
    for entry in entries:
            rowLen = len(entries)
            colLen = len(entries[0])
            for c in range(colLen):
                for r in range(rowLen):
                    print( entries[r][c])

def hallo1():
        print(data)
        
def hallo12():
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df)

button=Button(root,text="krijg",command=hallo).grid(row=12,column=0)
button1=Button(root,text="kxcvxrijg",command=hallo1).grid(row=13,column=0)
button3=Button(root,text="kxcvxrijg",command=hallo12).grid(row=14,column=0)

data = []

root.mainloop()
```

this above my code without error but the result is below we need the cell value for save to df and export to excel
[Running] python -u "d:\MFA\pythonfile\ttta.py"
.!entry
.!entry3
.!entry5
.!entry7

Please guide me and send the right code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(10):
    en = Entry(root)
    en.grid(row=i, column=0)
    entries.append(en)
    
    en1 = Entry(root)
    en1.grid(row=i, column=1)
    entries.append(en1)

def hallo():
    for entry in entries:
        data.append(entry.get())
```

replace lines 7->20 ( with the code above ) and I assumed you have the Excel export code so this is all you should need. hope it helps